# Mysql vs MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am using Mysql, now i would like to upgrade to MariaDB.
The MariaDB guy say: "MariaDB is a binary drop in replacement for MySQL"

Anybody who have used and using MariaDB, please suggest me: should or don't should to switch to MariaDB from Mysql and the reasons why!

I would like the suggests come from experience.

Thank for any suggestions!

Comment: Why not to postgresql then?

Comment: @zerkms Thank for your reply, `PostgreSQL can be an over-kill and might appear less performant than the counterparts, such as MySQL` 
**see also** https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/sqlite-vs-mysql-vs-postgresql-a-comparison-of-relational-database-management-systems

Comment: if you develop the application for which it really matters - it's weird to see a question you asked. If you overgrew mysql - you should already know the answer.

Comment: @zerkms I have researched and know the advances, but i know via introduction. ok, so i have to know by myself, thank you again :-)

Comment: I can confirm that after wasting half a day trying to get MySQL working properly on High Sierra, `brew install mariadb` was faster.

Answer (score 2):

I installed MariaDB on my Arch Linux system yesterday. Works a treat. Easy to setup and configure. Lightweight and fast. Can't believe its free :). 
I say go for it.

Comment: "Lightweight and fast" --- isn't mysql like that?

Comment: Also check this out: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-versus-mysql-features/

Comment: MariaDB is faster my friend :)

Comment: it doesn't mean mysql is slow for you (or for someone else) :-) It's highly unlikely a person who asks a question about performance will ever suffer from performance issues of a particular DBMS, since the slowest part will be inefficient schema and queries. So "MariaDB is faster" is a buzzword. PS: something for you to think on this evening: facebook runs on mysql